# Twisted application without twistd

Tags: python, twisted, daemon

I've wrote a nice app for myself using the Twisted framework. I launch it using a command like:

```
twistd -y myapp.py --pidfile=/var/run/myapp.pid --logfile=/var/run/myapp.log
```

It works great =)

To launch my app I wrote a script with this command because I'm lazy^^
But since I launch my app with the same twistd option, and I tink the script shell solution is ugly, how I can do the same but inside my app? I'd like to launch my app by just doing `./myapp` and without a shell work around.

I've tried to search about it in twisted documentation and by reading twisted source but I don't understand it since it's my first app in Python (wonderful language btw!)

Thanks in advance for anyhelp.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to import the `twistd` script as a module from Twisted and invoke it.  The simplest solution for this, using your existing command-line, would be to import the `sys` module to replace the `argv` command line to look like how you want `twistd` to run, and then run it.

Here's a simple example script that will take your existing command-line and run it with a Python script instead of a shell script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from twisted.scripts.twistd import run
from sys import argv
argv[1:] = [
    '-y', 'myapp.py',
    '--pidfile', '/var/run/myapp.pid',
    '--logfile', '/var/run/myapp.log'
]
run()
```

If you want to bundle this up nicely into a package rather than hard-coding paths, you can determine the path to `myapp.py` by looking at the special `__file__` variable set by Python in each module.  Adding this to the example looks like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from twisted.scripts.twistd import run
from my.application import some_module
from os.path import join, dirname
from sys import argv
argv[1:] = [
    '-y', join(dirname(some_module.__file__), "myapp.py"),
    '--pidfile', '/var/run/myapp.pid',
    '--logfile', '/var/run/myapp.log'
]
run()
```

and you could obviously do similar things to compute appropriate pidfile and logfile paths.

A more comprehensive solution is to write [a plugin](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/tap.html) for `twistd`.  The [axiomatic](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~divmod-dev/divmod.org/trunk/view/head:/Axiom/axiom/scripts/axiomatic.py#L75) command-line program from the Axiom object-database project serves as a tested, production-worthy example of how to do similar command-line manipulation of `twistd` to what is described above, but with more comprehensive handling of command-line options, different non-twistd-running utility functionality, and so on.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for you answer. I've already write my app as a plugin (well now I know how to set in my code options like logfile and pidfile). Wrap up twistd as a library is exactly what I want :) Your example is a bit complicated for me but I'm trying!

Comment: How about `from twisted.scripts.twistd import run; from sys import argv; argv[1:] = ['-y', 'myapp.py', '--pidfile=/var/run/myapp.pid', '--logfile=/var/run/myapp.log']; run()`

Answer (score 0):

You can also create the options / config for a twisted command and pass it to the twisted runner.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import twisted.scripts.twistd
import twisted.scripts._twistd_unix

config = twisted.scripts._twistd_unix.ServerOptions()
config.parseOptions([
  "--nodaemon",
  "web",
  "--listen=tcp:80",
  "--path=/some/path"
])
twisted.scripts._twistd_unix.UnixApplicationRunner(config).run()
```